# How to work with MessageBag Laravel Jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

i want to add messages to the MessageBag (or similar) for validate user credentials on laravel jetstream.

I have an a select2 for pick an option, and a user/password fields. When i sumbit form with the user field void the required attribute doesn't work.

I want to validate that the field it's empty and reload the same login page with an error message.

Thanks a lot !

I tried to program an a validation code in Fortify::authenticateUsing function but doesn't work.